21.7.B. EXERCISE FOAG VAKIL. Degree of a coherent sheaf equals the ramification order.
I am studying the Riemann-Hurwitz formula from Vakil's book the Rising Sea, and there is an exercise that states de following:
Show that the degree of $\Omega_{X/Y}$ at $p \in X$ is precisely the ramification order of $\pi$ at $p$. (The degree of a coherent sheaf on a curve was defined in x18.4.4. To do this exercise, you will have to explain why a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ supported on a finite set of points has a “degree” at each of these points, which sum to the total degree of $\mathcal{F}$ .)
I do not know if I have to use a specific formula of the degree of coherent sheafs, because the refered point define the degree with Euler characteristic, which I find really strange. Any help will be useful since I am really lost. I have also tried to look for other bibliography but normally all of them simplify it to the algebraically closed field case so it useless.
(Edit: The definition I have for the degree is
If ( C ) is a projective curve and $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $C$, the degree of a coherent sheaf $ \mathcal{F} $ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\deg \mathcal{F} = \chi(C, \mathcal{F}) - (\operatorname{rank} \mathcal{F}) \cdot \chi(C, \mathcal{O}_C).
\end{equation}where $\chi$ is the Euler's characteristic and the rank is by convention the rank of the sheaf at its generic point.)

Please start by writing down the definitions in this post via an [edit], especially the formula for degree from the referenced exercise. (This is actionable advice any time you're "really lost".)
